# Reverse DNS is finding someone else's domain

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, mx-record, reverse-dns

When I do a reverse DNS of my IP address I'm finding a different server name? This isn't my domain name. I was testing my mail server and it gave that warning. How do I fix it?

```
$ nslookup

Default Server:

Address: 192.168.16.1

> 184.82.92.84

Server:

Address: 192.168.16.1

Name: mail.productservicestuv.com

Address: 184.82.92.84
```

Answer (score 6):

The reverse DNS (which is a PTR record in the in-addr.arpa zone) is set by whoever owns the IP allocation. You need to ask whoever provided the IP to you (e.g. the ISP or hosting provider) to change the record.